# as3 difference between two ways of function declaration

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

While working on a P2P client in AS3, I stumbled over something I'd like to fully understand.

While this works:

```
private function test():void
{
    _sendStream = new NetStream(_nc, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
    var c:Object = new Object;
    c.onPeerConnect = function(subscriber:NetStream):Boolean 
    {
        trace("onPeerConnect");
        return true;
    }
    _sendStream.client = c;
    ...
}
```

This does not work:

```
private function test():void
{
    _sendStream = new NetStream(_nc, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
    _sendStream.client = this;
    ...
}

public function onPeerConnect(subscriber:NetStream):Boolean 
{
    trace("onPeerConnect");
    return true;
}
```

without going into the details of the particular problem at hand (onPeerConnect is just a callback function called on the client object of the NetStream object at some point), what is exactly the difference between the two ways of function declaration and what could be the reason that one way works, while the other does not in this case?

Comment: Hmm, something subtle should be the case of tis. Try declaring your class `dynamic` at first, and use the second approach, if it'll work, this will have to do something with dynamic property retrival mechanism. Also, check if `public var onPeerConnect:Function=this.peerConnect; function peerConnect(subscriber:NetStream):Boolean {...}` works, in conjunction with second approach.

Comment: Using `...` where you did makes this question hard to answer. Please include the whole function. Also, what is the output on the Flash trace log when this error happens?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I mean, this looks like something that should work.  At least when using NetConnections' clients to call functions back and forth (as opposed to NetStreams'), the second approach is closer to how I've always set things up in the past.  itcouldevenbeaboat's suggestion may be the key to finding out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I believe I found the issue. This seems to specify the issue :

**The NetStream.client object can call the following functions and receive an associated data object: onCuePoint(), onImageData(), onMetaData(), onPlayStatus(), onSeekPoint(), onTextData(), and onXMPData().**

So you need to explicitly set the callback for your onPeerConnect function, and I think @Vesper in the comments was on the right track likely and this should work :

```
class CustomClient
{
    public var _sendStream:NetStream;

    public function CustomClient()
    {    
         _sendStream = new NetStream(_nc, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
         _sendStream.client = this;
         _sendStream.onPeerConnect = this.onPeerConnect;
    }

     public function onPeerConnect(subscriber:NetStream):Boolean 
    {
        trace("onPeerConnect");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your first code block works because you are setting the callback for onPeerConnect explicitly.

In the second, you have not done that.

Comment: as stated in my question, this is exactly what does not work for some reasons (assigning 'this' to client is the same thing as you are doing here, since I declared onPeerConnect as class function of 'this'). Doing it this way, onPeerConnect does not get called.

Comment: In your example you set the client to this and we have no idea what the class is. You posted incomplete code. If your code is not working as described, should we just assume that you did it correctly ? Sorry, but `...` and providing no error message but instead a vague "this does not work", forces people to make assumptions. Does that mean you are getting an error or does that mean you are not getting your trace ? Yes, those details are what any programmer would use to figure out the problem. Help us help you.

Comment: updated the answer. Vesper's second suggestion in the comments above was on the right track. I initially followed your assumption that setting the client to a given object was enough. However, onPeerConnect must be set explicitly.